# Creating Flyby from path with ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, animation

I'm currently trying to create an animation with ArcScene along a given path. When I follow the Esri procedure [Moving the camera or view along a path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/animation/how-to-move-the-camera-or-view-along-a-path.htm), I do not get the expected results. I end up with no data represented on my screen.

My data for this example are :

1. a simple DEM, with a base heights floating on a custom surface (the DEM surface)
2. a line with a given offset floating on the same surface. The camera is supposed to follow that line.

[image: DEM and camera path]

From this point, I select the red line and go in the Animation menu to select the "Create Flyby from Path" option. I tried to fiddle with all the options (Path source, simplification factor, Path destination, orientation settings,...). However, it seems that the camera view that does not focus on my data. It is like if the camera is moved far away from the destination data (the screen is totally white during the animation time).

When looking at the Animation manager, it seems to me that the Target:X, Target:Y and Z make sense since they do correspond to the coordinates of my data.

[image: Coordinates of middle of line and Animation manager]

Yet, when I go manually to a view that I would like to obtain, the Animation Manager gives me totally different values.

Am I missing something ?

[image: Animation manager]

I would like to avoid the manual way to do so with the fly function as it is hard  to control precisely the flight speed/direction and impossible to reproduce this same flight several times.

Comment: Perhaps drop your line closer to ground, it sits above highest peaks now.

Comment: Thanks for the input @FelixIP but this doesn't work either... Still the same problem.

Comment: I can even make the line go through the peaks, I still get the same result. Could it be a projection issue ? I'm running out of ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
1.create a new shape file in ArcGIS 10.5 (I am using this version),
2.define projection,
3.check coordinates will contain M, Z, click OK,
4.start editing and add line and save
5.interpolate this line with dtm.

In ArcScene:
1.add dtm,
2.add path line created in ArcGIS,
3.select select lines in path line layer,
4.go to animation and create flyby from path,
5.vertical offset 10000, orientation settings - use path inclination + (-30); try different values,
6.import
7.enjoy animation!

Interesting that this "create flyby from path" works with shape file and not with geodatabase.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Just tried with simple path line created in geodatabase with projected coordinate system and it works. The main thing is that the path line should be in projected coordinate system and not in decimal degrees system.